# Cannot refer to a Named Range collection item

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with my code.

I have looked on Google but couldn't find any example helping me solving my issue.

In my Excel I have named a range containing 3 different cells.

Named range --> Location = refers to "E36;S58;E84"

I want to use the second cell in the collection to update it with data.

I dont know how I can refer to it?

I dont want to use:

> thisworkbook.activesheet.range("S58")

I have tried:

> thisworkbook.activesheet.range("location").cells(2,1) = x 'but this is not
>   working

Is there a way how to manage this issue.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: 1. Instead of using `ActiveSheet`, use the actual sheet name. 2. Use the [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-areas-property-excel) property of your range - `...Range("location").Areas(2)`

Comment: Thank you Works! :)

Comment: I found just `Range("Location").Cells(2) = 5` worked as long as the correct workbook was selected (having the correct sheet selected doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to BigBen!

The named range is an Area -> 1 dimensional.

The solution:

refer to the collection item via Areas property.

In my case:

> thisworkbook.activesheet.range("location").Areas(2) = x